# Convert a long to decimal

Tags: java

I've tried to look around for a solution to this, but I simply can't.
I want to show the megabyte representation of a long that is calculated in bytes.

In Java, you got a method called length() that you can invoke on a file object. It will return the files size in bytes stored in a long.
Now, I want to that long and turn it into megabytes rather than bytes. A file I am trying with got the size 161000 bytes. If I am not mistaken, that translates to 0.161 megabytes. So I would do bytes / 100000 and I would expect to get 0.161. The problem is that I don't.

If I go to my Windows Calculator, or any other calculator for that  matter, the application can manage to show those 3 decimals. Why is it that I can't do this?
I tried to store the result in a double, which just comes out as 0.0

EDIT:
An answers has been found.
Thanks to wrm:

long b = file.length();
            double mb = (double) b / (1024 * 1024);

Comment: FWIW, `1MB = 1024 * 1024` bytes. Not `1000 * 1000` bytes as many believe.

Comment: Actually, it's commonly 1000 for disk storage and 1024 for memory. In any case, the OP states they're dividing it by 100000 (10^5) which is off by a factor of 10 - it should be 10^6 (or 1024^2). That _might_ be a typo and we'd be able to tell if the OP had _actually given us the result they're getting_ :-) All problems should have (1) the smallest complete code sample that has the proble, (2) the expected behaviour and (3) the actual behaviour.

Comment: It's a question of [MB vs MiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)

Comment: wrm solved it!
You can see it further down. Thanks for being so fast though! :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe a little code would clarify the problem but i think, you have some kind of implicit conversion going on.
something like this should work:

```
double result = (double)myLongVal / 1024.0;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I did double mb = (double) b / (1024 * 1024); and it works great :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert one of the arguments to a double, not just the result.

Try dividing by `1000000.0` instead.

Comment: wrm solved it!
You can see it further down. Thanks for being so fast though! :D

Answer (score 2):

What you do wrongis that you use Integral divsion, where you need to use floating point one.

If both your opernads are integral (long and int) you get inegral result - i.e.  it will have no decimal part.

If you want to have decimal divison, at least one of your opernads has to bee float or doule.
you get that by adding .0 to literal number, or using typed variable.

I would also suggest using BigDecimal class that will allways yield correct result, for longs and doubles cant represent all decimal numbers in their ranges. (they have limited precision)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) Class and format your result as how you wish.

```
double value = size / 1000.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");    //This should print a number which is rounded to 2 decimal places.
String str = df.parse(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Long size1 = size / 1000;
double value = (double) size1;
String str = String.valueOf(value);
```

This did the magic to us.